# Google Adsense is not accepting my Website with www

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, no-www, woocommerce

I have a local eCommerce site built in Wordpress/Woocommerce. If you visit HTTP://example.com it redirects to HTTP://www.example.com. I even tried to perm redirect www. to HTTP://example.com but did not work so I reverted to the original `htaccess` which is given below:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress



# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Comment: Are you not using HTTP**S**? The redirect to www is likely triggered by WordPress itself (there are no redirects in the `.htaccess` code you posted and if you attempt to remove www in `.htaccess` you will likely get a redirect-loop if WP is configured differently.) But what does this have to do with "Adsense is not accepting my Website with www"? Is www not intended to be your canonical hostname? _Aside_: You have conflicting `AddType` directives?

Comment: Thanks for the answer and pointing out conflicting AddType. Yes, I got a redirect loop when removing www. Adsense actually does not accept `www.example.com`. It only accepts `example.com`only.